# Wait for jQuery $.get function to finish before running code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the following, the `return` statement is being executed **before** the call to `$.get()` finishes. How can I change this?

```js
var aft = {};

aft.getToken = function (url) {

    var theToken;

    //Get the token value
    $.get(url, function (data) {

        theToken = $(data).find('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();

    }, "html");

    return theToken;

};
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't—at least not sensibly.  While there is an `async` property you can set on jQuery ajax requests, I've had **serious problems** trying to use it with a `false` value in the past.

Try to re-think what you're trying to accomplish:

```
var aft = { yourToken: '' };

aft.setToken = function (url, callback) {
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        this.yourToken = $(data).find('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();

        if (callback)
           callback.apply(this);
    }, "html");
};
```

And then:

```
aft.setToken("url.php", function() {
   alert("Token retrieved = " + this.yourToken);
});
```

Or, if your callback *only* needs access to the returned data, then you could more simply do

```
if (callback)
    callback(data);
```

And then

```
aft.setToken("url.php", function(dataReturned) {
   alert("Ajax data retrieved = " + dataReturned);
});
```

Comment: This is the closest to correct answer so far, but I don't see the point of using an object and `apply` to pass the value. Isn't it enough just to do `callback($(data)...);`?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen - that would work too.  Probably simpler.  Using apply gives the callback access to the rest of the object, if there's anything else the callback cares about

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Can I ask why you don't seem to think my answer is as accurate?

Comment: @refp: Because blocking calls (such as synchronous requests) do not belong in the event-based world of JavaScript in browsers. The whole option of making a request like that is a mistake, and I hope it gets deprecated in the future.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen so, if a user on SO asked for one thing we should try not to answer his questions properly but lead him in another direction? ("I'd like to pass a reference to a variable such as `var x = 1;` in javascript, how is that possible?" => "You can't, instead switch to C/C++ where this is most def' possible, it's much better.. javascript is for loosers". I provided OP with a detailed answer including an alternative/recommended solution, which too me is good enough to be regarded as a "correct" one.

Comment: @refp: There's nothing wrong with `var x = 1;`. However, there are many things wrong with synchronous requests. Just admit defeat and move along.

Comment: It was a simile, and obviously one which you didn't comprehend properly/applied the current situation in. I'm not facing defeat nor am I winning (pun intended), I answered the question and that's all I'm here to do. Though saying that this answer in question is "closer" to a correct one is, at least to me, a most stupid statement.

Comment: Forgot to mention your nick, and please excuse my poor writing.. @MattiVirkkunen

Answer (score 4):

jQuery supports this out of the box, set the option `async` to `false` and the function call will be synchronous, instead of asynchronous.

Though I'd recommend you to keep the request async, see the "**recommended solution**" at the end of this post.

- [jQuery.ajax() – jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> **async** (Boolean) Default: true
>
> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
>   false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not
>   support synchronous operation.
>
> Note that synchronous requests may
>   temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request
>   is active.

---

#### But I'm using `$.get`, that seems to be specific for `$.ajax`?

Yes, but under the hood they are exactly the same thing.

> **jQuery.get ()**:
>
> This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> $.ajax({
>   url: url,
>   data: data,
>   success: success,
>   dataType: dataType
> });
> ```

#### Sample implementation

```
aft.getToken = function (url) {
  var theToken;

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'html'
    success: function (data) {
      theToken = $(data).find('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
    },
    dataType: dataType
  });

  return theToken;
}
```

### Recommended solution

As stated by the previously mentioned comment from the jQuery documentation asynchronous requests are normally NOT recommended, and will most often to more harm than good.

Instead you should try to implement the functionality asked for by using a callback or similar.

A callback is a function passed to some other function to handle a certain event, such as the success of your data retrieval. Just as you are passing a callback to `$.get` in your own snippet.

Make your function `aft.getToken` accept a second parameter named `callback` which should be a function reference. Then call this function with the token replied by your ajax request as a parameter when data retrieval and "parsing" is finished.

```
aft.getToken = function (url, callback) {
  var dst_object = this;

  $.get (url, function (data) {
    dst_object.stored_token = $(data).find (
      'input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]'
    ).val ();

    callback (dst_object.stored_token);
  }, "html");
};

...

aft.getToken ('/path/to/file.html', function (token) {
  console.log ("Got token: " + token);
});

...

console.log (aft.stored_token);
```

Comment: This should really be a last-ditch solution that you only implement if callback functions or code reorganization absolutely won't work.

Comment: Do *not* use synchronous requests. Instead learn how to program using the event model, which JavaScript in browsers is pretty much based on.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Maybe instead of commenting on everyone's answers about what the OP shouldn't do, you could provide a useful answer to solve the OP's problem that meets your standards.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff: Adam Rackis already did that and I didn't feel like posting the same thing again.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Our posts are very different in style and readability,  as well as mine being more elaborate with links to sources where information is found (even if I pulled it out of the back of my head).

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen First priority should be to answer OPs question, providing him with "tips N tricks"/nicer/recommended solutions is a bonus.

Comment: @refp: No, if the OP is asking for something that's wrong, the first priority is to tell them why they're wrong, and then perhaps explain the correct way to them.

Answer (score 0):

The *callback* code by @Adam Rackis is working for me. In fact, if the content of the url is of json structure, you can directly refer the fields like this. Note that aft = { yourToken :'' } is just dummy since I am not using the value in this dictionary at all. I just want to get the user_id from the URL.

```
var aft = { yourToken: '' };
    aft.setToken = function(url, callback){
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            user_id = data[0]['user_id'];
            if (callback)
                callback(data);
        });
    };

    aft.setToken("https://XXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me",  function(dataReturned){
        alert("You user id is " + labeler);
```